# ShoppingList Objects and Classes

Tags: arrays, string, class, object, addition

public class ShoppingList{

```
String store;
int noItems;
String[]itemNames;
int [] itemCounts;

ShoppingList(){
store="";
noItems=0;
itemNames=new String [100];
itemCounts= new int [100];
}
ShoppingList(String str, int no){
    store=str;
    noItems=no;
} 
public String [] addItem(String article, int number ){

    for(int i=0; i<itemNames.length-1; i++){
        itemNames[i]=article;
        itemCounts[i]=number;       
    }
    return itemNames;
}
public int noTotalItems(){
    int anzahl=0;
    noItems=anzahl;
    for(int m=0; m<itemCounts.length-1; m++){
        anzahl=anzahl+itemCounts[m];
    }
    return anzahl;
}
public int getNumberOf(String produkt){
    int zahl=0;
    for(int k=0; k<itemNames.length-1; k++){
        if(itemNames[k]==produkt){
            zahl=itemCounts[k];
            return zahl;
        }
    }
    return zahl;
}
public String [] toString(ShoppingList l){
    return itemNames;
}
```

}

**public class ShoppingListTest{

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    ShoppingList l=new ShoppingList("Supermarkt", 100);
    l.addItem("Prosecco", 3);
    l.addItem("Milk", 4);
    l.addItem("Wine", 5);
    l.addItem("Eggs", 4);
    Out.println(l);
    Out.println("#total items: "+l.noTotalItems());
    Out.println("#Milk: "+l.getNumberOf("Milk"));
    Out.println("#Wine: "+l.getNumberOf("Wine"));
}
```

}**

> > Hi guys! I would be really thankful, if you can help me to solve my problem. This is my code with all classes, but when I compile the ShoppingListTest, I get the following Error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> >             at ShoppingList.addItem(ShoppingList.java:25)
> >             at ShoppingListTest.main(ShoppingListTest.java:5)"
> >     I am not allowed to create Lists I have to add the items to the String array"itemNames".

Answer (score 0):

This line: `ShoppingList(String str, int no){` needs to change to: `ShoppingList(String str, int no) { this(); // <-- HERE`.

Basically, in your test you are using a construct which does not initialise the required arrays, thus causing them to be `null`.

Calling `this()`, in your parametrized constructor will call the parameterless constructor you have, which in turn, initialises the required arrays and other variables.

Comment: **ShoppingList@2aae9190**
I can't print the store name "Supermarkt" instead of that I get something like that. I would be really thankful if you can also solve this problem. I tried to create a extra class but it did not work.

Comment: @huettl: When you are doing `Out.println(l)`, from what I am understanding the method prints to console. This, internally invokes the `toString()` method of the `ShoppingList` class. You will need to override your own version of the `toString()` method.